# ext js call method in controller from another controller

Tags: javascript, extjs

fyi, this is my first Ext JS project and using ExtJS6
I created a main border layout and each view has its own controller.

From the west view controller, how do I call a method in the center controller.

Should I provide more info?

The concept is, one the west border I have a combobox.  When the user selects a combobox it loads some stores with data.  Now using those stores, I want to call some custom functions I build in the CENTER view controller.  The reason they are built in the CENTER view controller is because they affect the grids that are sitting in the CENTER VIEW.

Here is my Main.js

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.main.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
xtype: 'app-main',

controller: 'main',

viewModel: {
    type: 'main'
},

plugins: 'viewport',   

requires: [
    'ExtApplication1.view.main.Header',
    'ExtApplication1.view.main.Footer',
    'ExtApplication1.view.main.Panel',
    'ExtApplication1.view.main.MainController',
    'ExtApplication1.view.main.MainModel',

    'ExtApplication1.view.mainmenulist.mainmenulist',
    'ExtApplication1.view.clientdetails.clientdetails'
],

layout: {
    type: 'border'
},

items: [{
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'clientdetails', //should be maintable
    title: 'Main Details Panel',
    flex: 1
}, {
    xtype: 'appheader',
    region: 'north'
}, {
    xtype: 'appfooter',
    region: 'south'
}, {
    region: 'west',
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    title: 'Main Menu',
    //flex: 2,

    xtype: 'mainmenulist' // 'mainmenuv4view' 'mainmenuv3view'

}]
```

});

Here is my WEST region controller, I want to fire event on combobox selection after two different stores are loaded.

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.mainmenulist.mainmenulistController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.mainmenulist-mainmenulist',

onComboboxSelect: function (combo, record, eOpts) {

    //load position store
    //load market store
    //calculate

    var selectedCID = record.get('ClientID');
    var targetGrid = Ext.getCmp('positionsGridID');
    var targetStore = targetGrid.getStore();

    //load positions store
    targetStore.load({
        params: {
            user: 'xxx',
            pw: 'xxx',
            cid: selectedCID
        },
        //load market data
        callback: function (records, operation, success) {
            var targetGrid2 = Ext.getCmp('marketsGridID');
            var targetStore2 = targetGrid2.getStore();
            targetStore2.load({
                params: {
                    user: 'stephen',
                    pw: 'forero',
                    cid: selectedCID
                },
                callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                    //Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Changes saved successfully.');

                    this.fireEvent('doSomething', 'arg1', 'arg2');
                    //ExtApplication1.app.getController('view.clientdetails.clientdetailsController').onClickCalculate();
                }
            });
        }
    });



}
```

});

here is my controller for CENTER region

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.clientdetails.clientdetailsController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.clientdetails-clientdetails',

init: function() {
    this.listen({
        controller: {
            '*': { // This selector matches any originating Controller
                doSomething: 'doSomething'
            }
        },
    })
},

doSomething: function (param1, param2) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Changes saved successfully.');
    //alert("Param1: " + param1 + "  Param2: " + param2);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to doing this is to create a controller event. Emit this event from one controller, and listen for it in another controller. This creates looser coupling than directly calling methods on controllers.

For example:

```
Ext.define('app.controller.ControllerA', {
    someMethod: function(){
        this.fireEvent('doSomething', 'arg1', 'arg2');
    }
});

Ext.define('app.controller.ControllerB', {
    init: function() {
        this.listen({
            controller: {
                '*': { // This selector matches any originating Controller
                    doSomething: 'doSomething'
                }
            },
        })
    },
    doSomething: function(param1, param2){
        alert("Param1: " + param1 + "  Param2: " + param2);
    }
});
```

You can do this in ExtJS 4+ I believe. There might be a better way to do it now with version 6, but I'm not sure.

Comment: the controller event sounds like a better option.  I tried and the event is not being launched or received.  I added the code above.  Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In ExtJS6 you don't have to use the init function to add the listeners:

First Controller

```
Ext.define('AwesomeController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.awesome',

    listen: {
        controller: {
            'amazing': {
                amazingEvent: 'onAmazingEvent'
            }
        }
    },

    onAmazingEvent: function(controller, arg1, arg2) {
        // ..
    }
});
```

Second Controller

```
Ext.define('AmazingController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.amazing',

    fooBar: function() {
        // ..
        this.fireEvent('amazingEvent', this, arg1, arg2);
    }
});
```

Its recommended to add the event source to the event. 
For further information on events read here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/events.html

Comment: thank you, I changed my code to your suggestion and am reading up on the sencha event docs.  appreciate it!